# Issue with the build for has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I get getting an error every time I try to save a model with a has_one association, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is the error message and code below [image]

user.rb

```
  has_one :user_options
```

user_option.rb

```
 belongs_to(
        :user,
        class_name: 'User',
        foreign_key: 'user_id',
        inverse_of: :user_options
    )
```

user_options_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @user_option = current_user.build_user_option(user_option_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_option.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user_option, notice: 'User option was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_option }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user_option.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
has_one :user_options
```

To

```
has_one :user_option
```

As per ruby conventions, you should use singular name for `has_one` & `plural` for `has_many` association.

As you have given `user_options` for `has_one` relationship, each instance of the User model will have access to `build_user_options` & not `build_user_option` Ref [`has-one-association-reference`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference)